# How to load an image if flash can't run

Tags: flash

I have a site with an animated flash logo. Is there a way to load an image instead of the flash when flash isn't installed / running properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use flash detection, if user hasn't flash installed you can provide alternative content

http://www.kirupa.com/developer/mx/detection.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could make animated Gif out of it and show the image

Answer (score 0):

I prefer swfobject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) for this. It has a place to provide alternative content and it's a javascript implementation. Just my preference though.